# angular access variable inside a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular.  I couldn't figure how to access a variable inside a function(). this is my  code

```
  mergeImages() {
    var imgurl;
    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    let img1 = new Image();
    let img2 = new Image();

    img1.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;
      context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
      img2.src = '../assets/sun.jpg';
    };
    img2.onload = function() {
      context.globalAlpha = 1;
      context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
      context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
      context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

       imgurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
      //console.log(imgurl)

    };
    img1.src = '../assets/moon.jpg';


     }
```

now I need to access "imgurl" from another method

```
 printvalue(){
   need to access imgurl
}
```

edit 1 -  problem is angular cannot find **var a** on **printvalue()** it's only working inside **function something()**

Comment: did you use typescript

Comment: yes I'm using typescript

Comment: local vs global variable ? i think it not angular/typescript issue.

Comment: please see my updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you want to make a scope variable and access throughout the component, 
earlier in angularJS, there was $scope variable where you could access that variable throughout, in the latest angular version you need to use `this` to access throughout.

so you need to try

```
     imgurl : string;
mergeImages() {

    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    let img1 = new Image();
    let img2 = new Image();

    img1.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;
      context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
      img2.src = '../assets/sun.jpg';
    };
    img2.onload = () => {
      context.globalAlpha = 1;
      context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
      context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
      context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

       this.imgurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
      //console.log(imgurl)

    };
    this.img1.src = '../assets/moon.jpg';


     }
```

Comment: problem is angular cannot find var a on printvalue() it's only working inside function something()

Comment: while assigning the value to a use this.a = 20 @StephenReynolds

Comment: @StephenReynolds also you are declaring a variable in dosomething function you need to declare that globally. check my updated answer

Comment: Actually already tried all these methods but no success I'll delete this question and repost it with original code.  anyway thanx for taking your valuable time to answer my question :)

Comment: ok stackoverflow don't allow me to delete this. so I'll edit this question

Comment: @StephenReynolds try adding my code given in an answer let is used for a function variable that means it will be undefined outside its function.

Comment: that seems great happy coding brother.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your code like this

```
let imgurl;
mergeImages() {

    var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    let img1 = new Image();
    let img2 = new Image();

    img1.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = img1.width;
      canvas.height = img1.height;
      context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
      img2.src = '../assets/sun.jpg';
    };
    img2.onload = () => {
      context.globalAlpha = 1;
      context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
      context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
      context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);

       this.imgurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
      //console.log(imgurl)

    };
    this.img1.src = '../assets/moon.jpg';


     }
```

Comment: problem is angular cannot find var a on printvalue() it's only working inside function something()

Comment: @ anas first of all thanx for  taking your valuable time to answer my question. when I tried to  declare letimgurl;   my ide gives error under "let" saying  "a constructor method or accseor or property was expected "

Comment: @StephenReynolds Have you used function keyword ? It is not supposed to use in angular

Comment: yes first I used that but then I changed it as you posted